# Delete duplicate records (effectively)

Tags: postgresql

**PostgreSQL 10.4**

I have a table:

```
Column   | Type
-------------------------
 id      | integer| 
 title   | character varying(200)
Indexes:
    "phrases_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "phrases_index" btree (title)
```

The content is as follows:

```
rinopt=# select count(distinct title) from phrases;
  count  
---------
 9787866
(1 строка)

rinopt=# select count(title) from phrases;
  count   
----------
 13573099
(1 строка)
```

I'd like to keep only distinct records:

```
delete from phrases where phrases.id not in (
    select id from (
        select distinct on (title) * from phrases
    ) as phrases_id
)
```

Well, this command have been working 16 hours and I can't predict when it finishes.

Almost 14 million records is not a tiny data base, but not unimaginable. It seems that I have made a very ineffective select statement.

Could you tell me whether it is possible to write a more optimal command to clean duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single subselect should be enough. You could probably delete phrases with equal titles with ids which are greater than the current one:

```
DELETE FROM phrases p WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT p1.id FROM phrases p2 WHERE p.title = p2.title AND p.id > p2.id
);
```

A JOIN-like delete is also possible:

```
DELETE FROM phrases p USING phrases p2 WHERE p.title = p2.title AND p.id > p2.id;
```

Both statements should keep the phrases with the least id per title.